# Convert to html using tex4ht with .ps and Tikz figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht

I am trying to convert a `.tex` file listed below to html using `tex4ht`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi
\newcommand\inputpstex[1]{\input{#1.pstex_t}}
\usepackage{tikz}       
\title{Test}
\author{S.~Oulhoussine}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\begin{figure}
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=8]
\draw[-][draw=red, very thick] (0,0) -- (.5,0);
\draw[-][draw=green, very thick] (.5,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [thick] (0,-.1) node[below]{0} -- (0,0.1);
\draw [thick] (0.5,-.1) node[below]{$a=b=1/2$} -- (0.5,0.1);
\draw [thick] (1,-.1) node[below]{1} -- (1,0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Test}\label{t}
\end{figure}
Autre
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\inputpstex{tunnel}
\caption{Circuit à diode tunnel.} \label{f:tunnel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here are the `.ps` and `.pstex_t` files
[tunnel.ps](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CUnzJpO4sXocLQ-zmA65lEjTKvlxn5CH)
[tunnel.pstex_t](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KyT4fkhZC2LGb_HW1Nzd_yVH_4lRtI-2)
I use this command

```
 make4ht -c my.cfg test.tex
```

With this configuration file `my.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,mathjax}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style type="text/css">\Hnewline
.MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}\Hnewline
</style>\Hnewline}}
\let\originputpstex\inputpstex
\renewcommand\inputpstex[1]{\Picture+{}\originputpstex{#1}\EndPicture}
\tikzset{every node/.style={/pgf/tex4ht node/escape=true}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Here is a screenshot of the obtained `.html` file
[image]

As you can see, the `.ps` image from the `.pstex_t` does not appear.
When removing the image converter lines in the `.tex` file

```
\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi
```

I get an image for the .pstex_t file and an image for the tikz picture. However, some mathematical symobls appears in wrong way in the tikz picture. 
I need help to solve that problem  please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def` TikZ driver needs the SVG output option, as it depends on `dvisvgm`. You also don't need the `\tikzset{every node/.style={/pgf/tex4ht node/escape=true}}` line in your `.cfg` file. You don't use TikZ driver that uses this setting. So your `.cfg` file can look like this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,mathjax,svg}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style type="text/css">\Hnewline
.MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}\Hnewline
</style>\Hnewline}}
\let\originputpstex\inputpstex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\inputpstex[1]{ \Picture+{}\originputpstex{#1}\EndPicture}
\makeatother
%\tikzset{every node/.style={/pgf/tex4ht node/escape=true}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Then there is the issue with your PS file. When I run  `make4ht` in the debug mode using:

```
make4ht -a debug -c mycfg.cfg test.tex
```

I can see the following error in the terminal output:

```
processing page 2                         
  PostScript error: undefined in run       
  Operand stack:                             
      --nostringval--
```

This means that your `pstex_t` file cannot be converted using `dvisvgm`. It can be converted using `dvipng`, but then your TikZ image cannot work.

`dvisvgm` seems to work with other sample PS files I've tried, but it fails with your file. So I've tried to fix the PS file itself I've managed it to get it work using the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps2eps -f $1
epstopdf ${1%.ps}.eps
pdftops ${1%.ps}.pdf
```

Basically, it is necessary to convert the PS file to EPS first, then EPS to PDF and then back to PS. With the fixed PS file, I got the correct result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you michal.h21. Can you please share the .ps file in order I made a test.

Comment: @michal.h21 excellent suggestion....

Comment: @SaïdOulhoussine sure, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dPAZQvSP2qCPX5A_NW1p1IPdaOfBYoD1/view?usp=sharing) it is.

Comment: Thank you for sharing michal.h21.

Comment: I retrey with your .ps file and it worked. I tried too to do the same procedure as you but under windows 7. I installed Cygwin for eps2pdf and pdf2ps. I used Perl and ps2eps program. Unfortunately, it does not work even with the same .ps file. I also notices that .ps figures without arrows work fine. When an arrow is in the original Winfig figure, the dvisvgm4ht conversion fail. I decide to create new figures with Winfig for the Tikz pictures and leave the dvisvgm4ht conversion. Thank you again for you help.